# How to create realistic steam in blender?

Tags: smoke-simulation

#### Situation

I created a fluid simulation of boiling water in a pot. Now I am trying to create photo realistic steam in blender. I want to show the steam rising up from the pot. Here you can see what I had in mind (only a picture; I want an actual animation of course):

[image: picture of pot with steam]

#### Problem

I was trying to realize this using a smoke simulation. But due to the reason that I am new to this I ran into some problems. I was not able to change the color of the smoke to a seethrough white. I also tried to make the smoke look less dense, but I couldn't find any ways to do so.

#### Question

Can someone tell me which settings I need to look into and what values to change them to? I attached my .blend file so you can check out what I got so far

#### .blend File

[image]

Comment: Read the Smoke simulation section on the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/index.html?highlight=smoke and the Volume section for cycles. To make the smoke less dense use a smaller value for the density in the smoke domain or use a multiply node to scale the density for the smoke domain's material. Smoke looks better if it is backlit and against a dark background, like in the reference image.

Comment: In addition to what cegaton said, also make sure the color of the smoke is completely white.  The way I like to do this is switch the color picker to HSV mode and type in 1 for the V slider.

Answer (score 1):

this might help some PS i hope you have success https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2m9Re8N78I
also try this node set up
[image: node setup]